# Error while looping in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to print the results of an specific json object. I am receiving

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

while trying to execute the following code:

```
$.getJSON("http://test.test.com/api/service/Something()?username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&$format=json", function( d ){
    var tr;
    results = d.d.results;
    for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
        tr = ("</tr>");
        tr.append("<td>" + results[i].something + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + results[i].something_2 + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + results[i].something_3 + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
```

I pretty much copied the code above from another question, obviously I am doing something wrong.
The error comes here > `tr.append("" + results[i].something + "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tr = $("<tr/>");
```

You were missing the `$`, and had the `/` in the wrong place.

Also:

```
tr.append("<td>" + results[i].something + "</td>");
          ^^^^^ missing
```

Comment: exactly ("<tr/>") results in a string which has append as undefined...while $("<tr/>") results in a jQuery object which has an append function associated with it.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you. Any idea why it doesn't print results? Now it doesn't give an error, yet I cant see the table. The API is working and I can see the objects from the console. Is there any mistake in my table code?

Comment: @Beginner Did you add the missing `<td>`?

Comment: Yes, it is like that only because I don't know how to escape from <code >

Comment: @Beginner Odd. Could you create a JSFiddle or Stack Snippet with your HTML included?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9u6f1rmL/

However I am not sure, how this helps, as it is jquery mobile project. I will try to fix it by myself, just (me being) not as good as needed in js.

Comment: pfff...i forgot to add <table>. Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`tr` doesn't have a function called `append`, because you never defined one.  Here's how you're creating `tr`:

```
var tr;
tr = ("</tr>");
```

So `tr` is likely just a string at this point.  You never define any functions on it, so this won't work:

```
tr.append(...);
```

Perhaps you meant to create a jQuery object?:

```
tr = $("</tr>");
```

Though in that case you're likely also looking to create the element, not close it:

```
tr = $("<tr/>");
```

(Note also that your first `append()` is missing the opening `td` element.)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
tr = ("</tr>");
tr.append("" + results[i].something + "</td>");
```

TO

```
tr = $("<tr/>");
tr.append("<td>" + results[i].something + "</td>");
```